# Pandas - InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I have 2 dataframes, with one that contains company data and the other that has some employee count details as shown below:

**df1:**

```
cust_id,name,count
1,abc,
2,def,
```

**df2:**

```
account,count
abc,4
klm,1
```

**I am trying to generate the below output (Expected output)**:

```
cust_id,name,count
1,abc,4
```

**Given below is what I have thus far**:

```
df2_updated = df2.reset_index()
df1['count'] = df1['cust_id'].map(df2_updated.set_index('name')['count'])
```

On running the above I keep getting the below error

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

On running the below I find no duplicates. Could anyone assist

```
df2_updated.index.get_duplicates()
```

Comment: Check your df1 definition, you say there's cust_id, name and count, which are the contents of  your expected output

Comment: @GerardoFlores, I am trying to populate value for the field labelled 'count'. Its an empty field but I am trying to get the values for that based on the other existing columns.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='name', right_on='account', how='left', sort=False)
```